# Execute value in two table

Tags: mysql

I want to execute value from two tables. I have write query to execute value but i don't know is it wrong or true. I provide in following in query.

```
"SELECT a.id,a.name,b.address,b.pin FROM table1 a,table2 b WHERE a.id=b.id";
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking; “execute value” is not phrasing that makes much sense here to begin with. Please go read [ask], and then properly explain what you want to achieve. Include a proper description of your database structure and example data, if necessary to understand your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I want to execute value from two tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to JOIN the two tables. You are trying with an implicit JOIN notation that is deprecated and you should do it with an explicit JOIN like this:

```
SELECT a.id,a.name,b.address,b.pin 
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
```

This is untested since you didn't provide examples of your data but you can read it as:

> Select id and name from table a, address and pin from table b joining
>   them on the id field of each that must match. Swow only those records
>   that match.

You can read more [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)